# How to filter List<object> using Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, filter

Here is my scenario

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>();
obj.Add(new {id = 1, name = "Jakob"});
obj.Add(new {id = 2, name = "Sam"});
obj.Add(new {id = 3, name = "Albert"});
obj.Add(new {id = 1, name = "Jakob"});
```

How do you filter `List<object>` like these so it returns a List of users with name "Jakob"?

`obj.Where(t => t.name == "Jakob")` doesn't work

Comment: You'd be better off initializing an array so it will take on the anonymous type like `var stuff = new [] {new {id=1, name = "Jakob"},....};`  That way when you do the `Where` the lambda will know the type and you can access the properties.  Either that or switch from `object` to `dynamic`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use reflection

```
    var l = new List<object>();
    l.Add(new {key = "key1", v = "value1"});
    l.Add(new {key = "key2", v = "value2", v2="another value"});
    l.Add(new {key = "key3", v = "value3", v3= 4});
    l.Add(new {key = "key4", v = "value4", v4 = 5.3});

    var r = l.Where(x=> (string)x.GetType().GetProperty("key")?.GetValue(x) == "key1");
```

Get the type of your elements and find the property you are looking for. Then get the value for the current instance and compare it to the value you want to filter for.

But on the other hand, this approach has the advantage of working even if the List contains items of several different anonymous types (if they have different properties), as long as they all have the property you are filtering for.

EDIT

With c# 6 you can use the `?` operator, which is sort of an inline check for null. Ie, if `GetProperty()` returns `null` because the property is not found, the expression returns `null` without executing `GetValue()` (which would otherwise throw a `NullReferenceException`)

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for me. I guess reflection was the only solution. I normally walk away from Reflection but desperate time calls for desperate measures. I was too deep that I couldn't use other methods.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert your object to dynamic, it should work:

```
obj.Where(t => ((dynamic)t).name == "Jakob")
```

**EDIT**:

For completeness, I should mention couple of things:

- Usage of dynamic type comes down to usage of object with reflection on top of it, so eventually you don't get something better than reflection if you use this approach.
- Usage of dynamic at all involves loading necessary assemblies (a.k.a. DLR) into CLR, which would not load if you don't use dynamic at all. In other words, it's an overhead.

So, use with your own discretion.

Comment: like your idea but it throws " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'"

Comment: But it worked for me... are you sure you provided the exact code that you have? I just tried in VS 2013, works just fine.

Comment: I tried "obj.Where(t => ((string)((dynamic)t).name).Contains("Jakob")"

Comment: Too much noise in your expression. Simply do this if you want to use Contains method: obj.Where(t => ((dynamic)t).name.Contains("Jakob")); this will work because properties of dynamic are also dynamic. BTW, I also tried this and works fine. If it does not work for you, should be something else that you are not posting here.

Comment: sorry I can't get it to work anyway's I don't want to waste your talent in this thread as I was going to use answer from this thread in a less used area of the code but Thanks for your time and educating fellow humans :)

Comment: Not a problem absolutely :-) if you're getting the error you posted, probably one of the items don't have the name property on it. But anyway, do whatever you feel is right, nothing to apologize for. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The best option you have is to declare a class that represents a user.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a list of `User` objects and query this list.

```
var users = new List<User>
{
    new User { Id = 1,  Name = "Jakob" },
    new User { Id = 2,  Name = "Sam" },
    new User { Id = 3,  Name = "Albert" }
}

var filteredUsers = users.Where(user => user.Name == "Jakob");
```

Otherwise, you have to rely on the solution that Tengiz suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative is create array of anonymous types and then convert it to list via `ToList` `IEnumerable` extension method:

```
var obj = (new[] {
    new { id = 1, name = "Jakob" },
    new { id = 2, name = "Sam" },
    new { id = 3, name = "Albert" },
    new { id = 1, name = "Jakob" }}).ToList();
obj.Where(c => c.name == "Jakob");
```

If you don't really need a list and array is fine too - just don't convert to list. Benefit is you got strongly typed list and not list of arbitrary objects.

Comment: You neither need the `new[]` nor the `ToList()` to do the query, when you can initalize the collection at creation, because `obj` is then an instance of `IEnumerable<anonyomusType>`. The problem is, when you can't initialze on creation.

Comment: Author did not say he cannot initialize  on creation. ToList is for cases when author needs to add more objects later.